# A Hunter wants to get on a Bus

Tags: mathematics, geometry

A hunter wants to get on a bus, but belongings which have larger than 1 meter dimensions is not allowed.

So how will he be able to get his rifle (which is 1.5 meters) together with him without changing the shape of it ?

Answer (score -3):

Cut it in half? If you do it exact it will be the exact same shape but half as long, and therefore he will have two shapes that are 0.75m long (so no shape is breaking the 1.5 meter dimension rule), it might not be a clever read through the lines answer (the one you probably wanted) but with the way you have worded this question, it is a correct answer :P